# Check if logged in user via SSH did go through Active Direcory

Tags: linux, ssh, pam, sshd

I'm trying to check if a user who connects to a linux server via SSH is authentificated using Active Directory (Centrify).

In case he uses a local account (located in `/etc/passwd`), I need to display a warning asking him to use his Active Directory account and then prompt login again.

My first attempt was using PAM module pam_script inside `/etc/pam.d/login` to execute a script that checks if the current username exists in /etc/passwd whenever a user log in, display a warning if found and call the `login` command again.

I added the following line to `/etc/pam.d/login`

```
session    required    pam_script.so runas=root
```

This line execute a script file located in `/etc/security/onsessionopen` which contain:

```
#!/bin/sh
username=$1

if [ $(grep -c '^'$username':' /etc/passwd) = 1 ] 
then
    echo "Warning, please user your AD credentials"
    login
fi
```

But the same scenario didn't work in `/etc/pam.d/sshd`.
When using SSH the script does run but doesn't display text or prompt for login.

Any thoughts ?
Thank you

Comment: Perhaps this question is more suited for http://unix.stackexchange.com/ or perhaps http://superuser.com/ .

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I will check them